# IE 11 "Crashes" when Using Dynamic SVG Elements

Tags: javascript, html, svg, knockout.js, internet-explorer-11

I recently implemented a custom SVG Icon control for my company's new html application. Not long After it was implemented our quality department started reporting that IE 11 randomly "crashes" when using the application.

I am not sure the term crash accurately describes what is happening though. The application gets to a state where elements will no longer accept mouse or keyboard input nor will the display change to show hover styles. However, the cursor image will change appropriately as you hover over buttons and input element and scrollable sections can be scrolled using the mousewheel (but only the mousewheel).

I ran the UI Responsiveness Profiler when the application was in this state and found that there were no client side scripts running, just IE's garbage collector. After a week of testing I finally determined that the state is triggered when the user clicks on an icon generated with the svg  element but only when that click fires a function which removes the clicked svg  element from the DOM.

Here is a code pen that helps explain/recreate the issue:
http://codepen.io/GooeyIdeas/pen/WvpPzP

And the Minimum Code for Recreation:

```js
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.isLocked = ko.observable(false);
    this.toggleLock = function(){
      self.isLocked(!self.isLocked.peek())
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```css
svg use{
  cursor: crosshair;
}
svg{
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  cursor: default;
}
svg:hover{
  border-color: #dedede;
  background: #cecece;
}
#svg-icons{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>The cursor will change into a crosshair if you are hovering over the correct element.</div>
<div>
  <!-- ko if: isLocked    -->
  <svg class="ux-icon-svg" width="24" height="24"><use data-bind="click: toggleLock" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#locked"></use></svg>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko ifnot: isLocked -->
  <svg class="ux-icon-svg" width="24" height="24"><use data-bind="click: toggleLock" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#unlocked"></use></svg>
  <!--/ko-->
</div>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg-icons">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="unlocked">
    <path d="M18,9h-1V7c0-2.8-2.2-5-5-5S7,4.2,7,7h1.9c0-1.7,1.4-3.1,3.1-3.1s3.1,1.4,3.1,3.1v2H6c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v9c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2
             h12c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2v-9C20,9.9,19.1,9,18,9z"></path>
  </symbol>
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="locked">
    <path d="M18,9h-1V7c0-2.8-2.2-5-5-5S7,4.2,7,7v2H6c-1.1,0-2,0.9-2,2v9c0,1.1,0.9,2,2,2h12c1.1,0,2-0.9,2-2v-9C20,9.9,19.1,9,18,9z
             M15.1,9H8.9V7c0-1.7,1.4-3.1,3.1-3.1s3.1,1.4,3.1,3.1V9z"></path>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Has anyone encountered this before? Does anyone know of a work around that will still let me use the SVG 'use' element? Do I need to clarify anything?

*edit
It seems that some people are not able to reproduce this error. I would like     to know if anyone else can reproduce this error and if you can't, what version of windows are you running?

**edit
It is looking like this bug does not exist on Windows 8 PCs. To be sure I added CSS to my examples that will change the cursor into a crosshair when you are hovering over the svg use element since that is the element you have to click to trigger the crash.

Comment: It seems that some people are not able to reproduce this error. I would like to know if anyone else can reproduce this error and if you can't, what version of windows are you running?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue from the fiddle, running in a win server 8.1 IE11

Comment: It is looking like this bug does not exist on Windows 8 PCs. I added CSS to my examples that will change the cursor into a crosshair when you are hovering over the svg use element since that is the element you have to click to trigger the crash. Just to ensure that we are not miss clicking

Comment: what win machines are you using?

Comment: I can confirm the bug now on my win 7 machine, thought i didn't have IE 11 there initially. But as far as workaround I dunno. Assuming you have to use, the <use>, why not create two different svg icons and just toggle manually? it's not ideal, but it'll stop the issue from stopping the rest of the page

Comment: Cool, I almost glad someone else was able to reproduce the issue. For my project I am able to set {pointer-events: none;} for all use elements to keep the issue in check. But, {pointer-events: none;} does not work for IE 10 or below so a more robust solution would be nice to have for other readers who have this issue and have to support older versions of IE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79818/discussion-between-kenneth-moore-and-daemedeor).

Comment: I've just spend a morning finding out I have exactly this problem (removing a use element sort of hangs the browser). I can confirm It only occurs on Windows 7, IE11. Thanks for researching this, I'll try and find another workaround.

Comment: I can't believe I just wasted a whole work day on this... How can this not be worthy of a patch?! Have you ever seen the episode of family guy where they show what the world would look like without religion? I wonder what the web would look like without IE11...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Since there hasn't been much traffic with this post I guess I will post a solution:
I added this CSS rule:

```
svg use {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This is not ideal but it keeps IE 11 from locking up and that is all I am required to support with this project. However I would like for this post to help others in the future who might encounter this bug and do need to support older versions of IE. If anyone is willing to take the time to come up with a more robust solution I will accept that as the answer to this post.

Also should I file a bug report to microsoft regarding this issue?

Comment: Hi. Just to let you know, I've tested this on two separate PCs, and also asked a couple of other people to try it as well. None of us have been able to reproduce the issue you've described. Given the lengths you've gone to to diagnose it and describe it, there clearly is an issue, but I can only guess that there's something more to it that you haven't mentioned. I'd recommend filing a bug on [MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) and include a hang dump of the tab content process (privately) attached to the bug.

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you using the codepen site or the min markup to test? Also, what version of windows are you testing on? We are running 64bit windows 7 and our quality team has found issues with IE 11 that present differently on different operating systems, perhaps this is one of them?

Comment: I just tested 10 different PC's in my office and was able to reproduce the "crash" on all of them. I ran Internet Explorer 11 (No Add-ons).

Comment: I tried both the codepen and the test on this page; they both worked fine for me. All my tests were on Win8.1 machines, so that could be the significant difference.

Comment: That seems likely. I did update the fiddle and the snippet to make ensure that it is being tested properly. Don't know why didn't think to put the click bindings on the use elements to begin with... If you wouldn't mind double checking with the updated examples I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @KennethMoore referring to the question you asked and confirmation that it only is reproducible on win 7, you could file a bug report with microsoft, i just don't think it will go anywhere

Comment: I ran into the same problem and this solution works for me too.Thank you very much, you saved my day!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer so much. I hate IE.

Comment: Microsoft would do the world a favour by stop developing IE/edge! So many waisted hours of my life... Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I just spent my entire afternoon troubleshooting this very issue until I stumbled across this post. I was starting to fear for my life as I'm using SVG icons quite extensively throughout my app, but your workaround saved me.

Comment: @Spudley facing the same issue today, and this is not the first time I see someone from microsoft unable to reproduce bug - that will never be resolved anyway - we know how this ends up with Internet explorer. Other microsoft products are great though! Good luck with your bug reproduction - or maybe I should say : try harder ?

Comment: @Ant - I'm not actually from MS. The other people I mentioned before are, but not me. But either way, I suspect you're right; I can't see this being fixed in IE11 now.

Comment: I can also confirm this is a problem only on Win7's version of IE11. This post was a lifesaver though. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the investigation and solution!
I confirm too: problem only on IE11 + Win7. On Win8 + IE11 it's not reproducible.
How on earth you figured out the solution with pointer-events?

Comment: Ran into the same problem. Bug occurs on Win7 IE11, not on Win8 IE11. Thanks for your research and solution!

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this with an `<svg>` that was dynamically added or removed from the DOM with AngularJS and `ng-if`.  The accepted solution did not work for me.  The solution that did work was to use `ng-show` instead which hides and shows the SVG instead of adding and removing it from the DOM.

Comment: Fortunately you apparently didn't need to use the 'ng-if' to hide your SVG element. Sometimes it is useful because it actually removes the hidden markup and allows certain CSS rules to work properly. If this was the case I would recommend wrapping your SVG element in a 'div' or 'span' tag with the class "dynamic-svg-wrapper". Assign the event that triggers toggling the display of SVG icon to the wrapper element. Then create this CSS rule: '.dynamic-svg-wrapper svg {pointer-events: none;}'

Comment: Could you perhaps update your answer with the icon that you were using that also caused this bug but didn't work with the css fix?