# IE11 is freezing (partially) after removing an element from the DOM and an object from an array

Tags: javascript

I am encountering some truly strange behavior in IE11.0.9600.18860 (W7). You can try the [demo here](https://matthew798.github.io/formr/demo.html). The demo page shows off a form building interface written in pure JS. The "toolbox" on the right contains some basic input elements that can be dragged into a column.

The problem is that when I try to delete (the garbage can icon) a control from a column, or the column itself, IE11 freezes, sorta... I can still use the IE GUI, but the *page content* doesn't work anymore.

The code executed when a column's garbage can icon is clicked:

```
removeButton.onclick = e => this.row.removeCol(this);
```

Row.removeCol():

```
removeCol(col = null) {
    let colIndex;

    if (col == null) {
        colIndex = this.data.columns.length - 1;
        col = this.data.rows[colIndex];
    } else if (typeof (col) == "number") {
        colIndex = col;
        col = this.data.columns[col];
    } else if (col instanceof Column)
        colIndex = this.data.columns.indexOf(col);

    col.dispose();
    this.data.columns.splice(colIndex, 1);
}
```

Column.dispose():

```
dispose() {
    this.row.workspace.controlSortable.removeContainer(this.dom);
    this.dom.parentElement?.removeChild(this.dom);
    this.removeButton.tooltip.dispose();
    delete this; <-- i've tried without this line
}
```

The above code is transpiled by babel, and bundled with webpack, if that makes a difference.

Even weirder is it seems to work *better* (not cured) when the console is open... This lead me to beleve it was something to do with `console` not being defined when debug tools isn't open, but no...

Can someone try it out? Thanks!

Comment: Can't reproduce, with console open or closed, site works without freezing

Comment: @PatrickEvans Grrr, happens on 3 machine with IE... 11.0.9600.18860

Comment: Yea mine is 11.55.17763.0 so might have been quite a few optimizations/fixes since that old version.

Comment: @PatrickEvans unfortunately I don't have control over the IE version on our PCs... I love IE so much.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Wait, are you running windows 7?

Comment: Windows 10, its the IE that came with it

Comment: @PatrickEvans That makes sense, 11.0.9600.18860 is the highest available on W7. Why would windows 7 users need bug fixes and performance improvements? Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it was crashing is because [insert ridiculous IE11 behavior here] when removing an svg element from the dom.

More info here [IE 11 "Crashes" when Using Dynamic SVG Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653533/ie-11-crashes-when-using-dynamic-svg-elements)